# The hierarchy of the type MyInBound is inconsistent when extending MessageInbound

Tags: java, servlets, websocket

For Broadcasting message from server am having servlet extending `WebSocketServlet`, inside am writing class which extends `MessageInbound` which results in compile time error in eclipse(hierarchy type inconsistent).

```
public class MyWebSocketTest extends WebSocketServlet {
    public class MyInBound extends MessageInbound{

     }
}
```

I suggested to put tomcat-coyote JAR Since Tomcat's `WsOutbound` has indirect dependency. Eventhough same error existing.

Comment: Please don't approve edits like this one. Take more time when reviewing, we should **REMOVE** `Java` from title, not adding it!

Comment: What's happening to the reviewers???